# How to add new column "Next_day_close" for stock price

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to add new column that have the close price next day.

[image: example]

The datas get from Alphavantage using pandas format.

NB: Sorry, I can't to add picture because of my reputation.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to add a column to hold the close price from the next day in the time series i.e. On row dated 2015-07-01, your new *Next_day_close* column should display the value of the *Close* column from 2015-07-02.

If that is really your requirement, then the following line should get you the result - assuming that your dataframe looks like the one you posted in the picture:

`df['Next_day_close'] = df['Close'].shift(-1)`

Comment: Thank you very much, sir!! it works.

'shift' all I need.